# Porque media queries funcionam assim?

Tags: html, css, html5, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Eu estava criando um menu responsivo, e u reparei que se eu não colocar os media queries do menor para o maior ele não funciona corretamente.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:560px) {
    .menu li {
        width: 132px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .menu li a {
        width: 132px;
        height: 50px;
        color: red;
        position: absolute;
        font: bold 18px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:960px) {
    .menu li {
        width: 132px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .menu li a {
        width: 132px;
        height: 50px;
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        font: bold 18px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque "o uso de Media Queries se dá de forma “crescente”, ou seja, primeiro aplicando estilos para dispositivos com resoluções menores".
http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/front-end/css/breakpoints-e-logica-em-media-queries.html
Talvez o motivo seja a facilidade para organização