# É possível usar 2 @media screen?

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Estou com um problema, uso o Media Queries: @media screen e ele esta configurado com `max-widht:375px`.
 quero colocar um @media screen para `max-widht:1024`

Tem como?

Comment: Sim, é possível. Quando fechar as chaves de um, você ja pode criar o outro. Leia mais: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Talvez isso te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224216/porque-media-queries-funcionam-assim

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58524/como-eu-trabalho-com-design-responsivo/58525#58525

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Tem como
Você pode declarar um e outro desta forma:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .tela{ 
         width: 400px;
     }
}
@media screen and (max-width:375px){
    .tela{ 
         width: 250px;
     }
}
```

se for apenas por um elemento, você pode também utilizar de JQuery para fazer essa verificação. Se quiser se informar, segue o [link](http://api.jquery.com/width/)